# Can't find my Google Chrome favorites on my computer

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I can't find my Chrome bookmarks on my computer. I have been on many websites and I got here: *C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default* but I can't open the bookmark part, it's just a blank paper on the side and when I click on the link it says that I have to choose a program to open it in, but I don't know what to choose. There is also something called  Bookmarks.bak but I can't open that either.

Comment: What do you want to open the bookmarks for, to add them to your bookmarks in Chrome, to see what the file looks like? If you just want to open the file to peek inside, use Notepad, but make sure the "Always use this program to open these types of files" is unchecked. The file is not meant to be opened by a user.

Comment: I want to sort through them and have easier access to the links.

Comment: that is best done through Chrome. Open up your `Bookmark Manager` by doing the key combination Ctrl+Shift+O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the bookmark bar in the chrome to access then inside the chrome itself. For this you have to go through the **Settings>Always show Bookmark bar** and in Bookmark bar drag and drop the bookmark as you like to see them.

[image]

But if you want to see the url's then you have to open the `bookmark.bak` using N++ and you can see them.

Comment: Thank you :) But if I am getting a new computer how can I get my Chrome bookmarks on the new one?

Comment: That's why there is sync option in chrome using your Gmail ID. Just sign in and then choose in settings what you want to sync there, and when you will sign in on other computer using same account you will get all of your stuffs.